# Ionic Cordova splash creens / icons

Tags: android, ios, cordova, splash-screen, ionic-framework

I'm designing an app with Ionic Framework for iOS and Android.
I configured splash screens and icons but I still have default Cordova splash screens and icons when I run the app on my phone (using `ionic run android`) or run on the iOS Simulator (using `ionic emulate ios`)

Is this normal or are my images badly configured?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Discover this new tool by Ionic for generating splash screens and icons : http://ionicframework.com/blog/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/

Answer (score 9):

To generate icons check out https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon

It automatically generates all the icons you need for cordova projects for both ios and android and copies them to the right folders.

You can also set it up as a hook to run automatically on every build.

Answer (score 0):

When we added our icon/splash image then we should insure that icon image's minimum dimensions should be 192x192 px, and should have no rounded corners. And splash image's minimum dimensions should be 2208x2208 px.

Answer (score 0):

Following the changes for ionic android app icons.

Go to your project directory - /resources/android/icon/add your icons here as per required size and names below.

> drawable-hdpi-icon.png - 72*72
>
> drawable-ldpi-icon.png - 36*36
>
> drawable-mdpi-icon.png - 48*48
>
> drawable-xhdpi-icon.png - 96*96
>
> drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png - 144*144
>
> drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png - 192*192

As well add the icons in the below directory if it's needed - project directory-/platforms/android/res/place the above icons as per specific folder.

And run the below terminal commands it'll update your icons same way you can manage your splash screen as well.

> $ionic build android
>
> $ionic run android